# How to get the newest object using the objectID in coredata multiple thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

when I changed an object property value in a thread and save,I can get the object using its objectID with objectWithID function in another thread, but I can not get the new property value which has been modified in previous thread？How can I get the proper value？

Comment: You can look up the object in another thread from the object ID. Did that not work?

Comment: yes，I can get the object with objectID in another thread, but can not get the newest property value when the object property value has been changed with other thread. I get the old object